# AS3 positioning audio spectrum/visuallizer

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, audio-streaming, audio-recording, spectrum

I've been looking for code for positioning the spectrum into the center of the flash screen, but unable to find it. I'm using the code below:

```
SoundMixer.computeSpectrum(liveBytes, false, 0);
var g:Graphics = this.graphics;
g.clear();
g.lineStyle(10, 0x000000);
g.beginFill(0x6600CC, 10);
for (var i:int = 0; i < 150; i++) {
drawSpectrum(liveBytes.readFloat() * 4, i);
}
```

the spectrum is displaying below the center of the screen(about 75% from top).

Answer (score 0):

You should use a child `Shape` or `Sprite` object's `graphics` property to draw on, because you then will be able to change the child's position to be the center of your stage or whatever area you designate.

```
var g:Graphics=spectrum.graphics; // "spectrum" is a child Shape
```

To further answer your question, it's required to see the `drawSpectrum` code. Also make sure `drawSpectrum` uses correct graphics object to draw upon.